# Why is Autocomplete not working for vim-jedi

Tags: vim, neovim, jedi-vim

I'm relatively new to Vim so there may be something obvious I'm missing here. I'm usig Neovim and have installed the vim-jedi plugin. When I'm typing, I can see that it's offering autocomplete options:
[image]

I can scroll down to this option (using the arrow keys) and hit Enter to have it autocomplete. However, if I hit `<Ctrl+Space>` then it does not autocomplete. I've looked at my `:map` and `<Ctrl+Space>` doesn't seem to be mapped to anything already. Can anyone please assist?

Comment: Why are you expecting `<C-space>` to complete?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble - the docs suggest as such:
Completion <C-Space>
from https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim

Comment: You didn't post any debug info. So hard to say why it's not working for you. Please just open an issue in jedi-vim's issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used that plugin before, but when using VIM normally I always do CTRL-p or CTRL-n to auto-complete a word that has already been typed once in my document. Then after highlighting the correct one, I hit space to confirm selection and also to continue typing the next word. Hitting CTRL-space should be unnecessary if it works in the same way as regular vim auto-complete.

You can also use CTRL-n or CTRL-p respectively to select which word is the correct one to auto-complete to.